# Deselecting option buttons when selected together

Tags: excel, vba

on my UserForm, I have created option buttons adjacent to the topic I want my users to choose i.e. if they choose "mechanical engineering" there is a "yes" option button or a "no" option button to the right of it. However, users cannot select classes "mechanical engineering" and "chemical engineering" together. I have entered the first code below which works. However, it only works if option button "Me.optFMME" and then "Me.optFMCE" in that order. If you choose them in the other order i.e."Me.optFMCE"  and then "Me.optFMME", it allows it. So, I entered code (the second one undernearth it) to counteract this but it doesn't do anything.

Please if anyone has any guidance, it would be much appreciated.

```
Private Sub optFMME_Click()

    If Me.optFMME And Me.optFMCE Then
        MsgBox "Mech Eng and Chem Eng cannot be selected together due to similar     material. Please select another combination."
        Me.optFMME = False
        Me.optFMCE = False
    End If
End Sub

`

Private Sub optFMCE_Click()

    If Me.optFMCE And Me.optFMME Then
        MsgBox "Mech Eng and Chem Eng cannot be selected together due to similar     material. Please select another combination."
        Me.optFMCE = False
        Me.optFMME = False
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You should break out that logic into a separate `Sub`. It's identical, so it should be in only one place. The order in checking the options (CE and ME vs ME and CE) should be irrelevant.

Comment: Hi Peter, thank you for your reply. As shown above I have put them in to different subs, or am I mistunderstanding? Sorry my skills within VBA are very limited.

Comment: You could give just a "Yes" option.  A "No" option being the option box not clicked.  The option buttons have a `GroupName` property - only one button with the same `GroupName` can be "Yes" at a time (a Null value in that property is a group as well).

Comment: Thank you, Darren! Very much Appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic for checking the option buttons is identical, so it should be isolated into a separate function. In this way, you remain consistent in your logic and if something needs to be adjusted, it's all in one place.

```
Private Sub optFMME_Click()
    LogicCheck
End Sub

Private Sub optFMCE_Click()
    LogicCheck
End Sub

Private Sub LogicCheck()
    If Me.optFMCE And Me.optFMME Then
        MsgBox "Mech Eng and Chem Eng cannot be selected together " & _
               "due to similar material. Please select another combination."
        Me.optFMCE = False
        Me.optFMME = False
    End If
End Sub
```